# How to sort chat list according to time of messages?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to sort my `users chat lists` according to the most recent chat (newest at the top and so on).
my `chat fragment` looks like this:

[image]

and this is a snippet from `chat fragment`:

```
 private UsersAdapter usersAdapter;
    private B_RecycleView recyclerView;
    private List<Chatlist> mChatUserList;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private List<Chat> mChats = new ArrayList<>();
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
       mEmptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.no_chats);
       recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
       recyclerView.hideIfEmpty(recyclerView);
       recyclerView.showIfEmpty(mEmptyView);
       fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
       mChatUserList = new ArrayList<>();
       mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
       usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getContext(), mUsers , true);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
       reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fUser.getUid());
       reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               mChatUserList.clear();
               for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chatlist chatlist = snapshot1.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                   mChatUserList.add(chatlist);
                }
               chatList();
           }
           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error){
           }
       });
```

Chat Model class:

```
public class Chat {
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String message;
    private String time;
    private String type;
    private boolean isseen;

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message,String time, String type ,boolean isseen){
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
        this.time = time;
        this.type = type;
        this.isseen =isseen;
    }
```

I have TimeStamp for every message like this:

[image]

[image]

I have tried this in my chatFragment:

```
  private void getChats() {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                mChats.clear();
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chat chat = snapshot1.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if(chat.getReceiver().equals(fUser.getUid()) || chat.getSender().equals(fUser.getUid())){
                        mChats.add(chat);
                    }
                }
                sortUsers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void sortUsers() {

    Collections.sort(mChats, new ChatTimeComparator());

    if(mChats.size() > 0 && mUsers.size() > 1){
        String lastUserRId = mChats.get(0).getReceiver();
        String lastUserSId = mChats.get(0).getSender();

        int i = 0, selId = 0;
        for(User user: mUsers){
            if(user.getId().equals(lastUserRId) || user.getId().equals(lastUserSId)){
                selId = i;
            }
            i++;
        }

        User user = mUsers.get(selId);
        List<User> tempUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        mUsers.remove(selId);
        tempUsers.addAll(mUsers);
        mUsers.clear();
        mUsers.add(0, user);
        mUsers.addAll(tempUsers);

        usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public class ChatTimeComparator implements Comparator<Chat>
{
    public int compare(Chat left, Chat right) {
        return right.getTime().compareTo(left.getTime());
    }
}
```

this sorts the latest chat only. The rest of the chats are ordered randomly.
How can I sort all the chats? any help? Note that I'm trying to sort the `chatlist`, not the messages.

**EDIT:**
I have added time to every chat according to the last message was sent in the chat like so :

```
 private void lastMessage(final String userid, final TextView last_msg, final TextView timeSent){
        theLastMessage = "default";
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                 for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                     Chat chat = snapshot1.getValue(Chat.class);
                     if(chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                             chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
                     {
                         long time = chat.getTime();

                         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
                         try {
                             calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
                         }
                         catch (Exception ex){
                             ex.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         final String pTime = DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", calendar).toString();
                         timeSent.setText(pTime);
                         if(chat.getType().equals("image")){
                             theLastMessage = "Sent a photo";
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             theLastMessage = chat.getMessage();
                         }
                     }
```

Here is the result of this snippet:

[image]

as you can see the chats are ordered randomly.
So, now can I sort the chat based on the time of the last message sent in that chat?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reordering the chat messages in the client, I recommend letting the database take care of this.

Based on your current code/data, this requires the following changes:

1. Store the timestamp as a number, not as a string. So in your `Chat` class change to: `private long time;`, and use that number everywhere.
2. Store the inverted timestamp (also as a number). Firebase Realtime Database can only return results in ascending order. You can either reverse the results in your application code, or store an inverted timestamp to order on. So `invertedTimestamp = -1 * timestamp`.
3. Use a query to get the chat messages in the correct order:

   ```
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    Query query = reference.orderByChild("invertedTimestamp");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        ...
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to do so without changing the time to long? because I'm using it everywhere, I'm afraid it would cause many errors. anyway, I will try and give you my feedback, thanks

Comment: 1) Not in a way that is guaranteed to always work. Numbers are sorted different than strings, and a timestamp is inherently a number. 2) And keeping it as a string means you can store its inverted value anyway. So: nope, sorry. You'll have to modify the code and data to fix that data type.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the chat items don't have timeStamp. as you can see from the first image. I only have a timestamp for every message. will your answer still work in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means. Your code (and thus my answer) only shows loading/ordering data from `Chats`.

Comment: Ah I now see: you're trying to sort the `Chatlist` for a user based on their last message. This is not possible, as you can only order on data that is at a fixed location directly under each child node that is returned. The common approach is to add a `lastMessageTimestamp` property on each child node of `Chatlist` and update that whenever you write a chat message too. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535831/firebase-realtime-database-structure-in-chat-app and https://stackoverflow.com/q/41704506

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. I'm trying to sort the Chatlist based on the last image, I have edited my post. Now I have the last message timeStamp.

Comment: but as you can see it is not a fixed value because each time someone sends a message the timeStamp of the last message will change, so the last message timeStamp is not saved in the database. Can you please check the last code snippet I added?

Comment: I've already explained how to best implement this in [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69129993/how-to-sort-chat-list-according-to-time-of-messages/69133683?noredirect=1#comment122192677_69133683). You're free to implement it differently of course, but I won't be able to help any further with that.

Comment: I will check the links

Comment: ok once I solve this issue, I will add my answer here.